# dplyr summary tables for list of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table

I have a data frame:

```
role <- c("hi", "hi", "lo", "lo", "me", "me")
a <- c("w", "r","w", "r", "w", "r")
b <- c("z", "x","z", "x", "z", "x")
c <- c("o", "o","p", "p", "t", "y")

df <- data.frame(role, a, b, c)
```

To get a pivot table style summary of which `role`s have what frequency of factors in column `a` I use dplyr:

```
summ <- df %>%
group_by(role, a) %>%
tally() %>%
spread(a, n, fill = 0)

summ
```

**How can I automatically generate separate pivot tables for all columns (`a`, `b` and `c`) using one dplyr pipe?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
names(df)[-1] %>% 
    map(~df %>% 
         select(.x, role) %>% 
         group_by(!!sym(.x), role) %>%
         tally() %>% 
         spread(!!sym(.x), n, fill = 0))
#    [[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    role     r     w
#* <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     hi     1     1
#2     lo     1     1
#3     me     1     1

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    role     x     z
#* <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     hi     1     1
#2     lo     1     1
#3     me     1     1

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#    role     o     p     t     y
#* <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     hi     2     0     0     0
#2     lo     0     2     0     0
#3     me     0     0     1     1
```

Comment: I tried your code but got `Error in sym(.x) : could not find function "sym"`. What packages did you use in addition to `tidyverse`? Thank you!

Comment: @thecatalyst  You may need `library(rlang)`

Answer (score 2):

One approach, retaining the code you used for a single pivot table:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -role) %>%
  split(.$key) %>%
  lapply(function(x){x %>% group_by(role, value) %>%
      tally() %>%
      spread(value, n, fill = 0)})

$a
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   role [3]
   role     r     w
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1    hi     1     1
2    lo     1     1
3    me     1     1

$b
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   role [3]
   role     x     z
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1    hi     1     1
2    lo     1     1
3    me     1     1

$c
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   role [3]
   role     o     p     t     y
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    hi     2     0     0     0
2    lo     0     2     0     0
3    me     0     0     1     1
```

Comment: So in this answer what is `key` and `value`?

Comment: `key` = a, b, c; `value` = values originally in those columns. These two variables are defined in the first line's `gather()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward in base R with `lapply` and `table`:

```
lapply(df[-1], function(x) table(df$role, x))
$a
    x
     r w
  hi 1 1
  lo 1 1
  me 1 1

$b
    x
     x z
  hi 1 1
  lo 1 1
  me 1 1

$c
    x
     o p t y
  hi 2 0 0 0
  lo 0 2 0 0
  me 0 0 1 1
```

This returns a list of table objects. If you want a list of data.frames, you could do

```
lapply(df[-1], function(x) as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$role, x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI You're also using `tidyr` for gather, and you can use `count` in place of the `group` then `tally` for a more concise pipe.

If you want a single table outlining all combinations:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -role) %>% 
  count(role, variable, value) %>% 
  spread(value, n, fill = 0)

    role variable     o     p     r     t     w     x     y     z
* <fctr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     hi        a     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
2     hi        b     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
3     hi        c     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4     lo        a     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
5     lo        b     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
6     lo        c     0     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
7     me        a     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
8     me        b     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
9     me        c     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: I was debating sharing a similar answer.  I had included `%>% select(role, variable, r, w, x, z, o, p, t, y) %>% arrange(variable, role)` at the end to group together the tables for slightly easier reading.